# Create multiple dataframes from one

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
name   time    session1    session2    session3
Alex   135      10             3           5
Lee    136       2             6           4
```

I want to make multiple dataframes based on each session. for example, i want to make dataframe one that has `name`, `time`, and `session1`. and dataframe 2 has `name`, `time`, and `session2`. and dataframe 3 has `name`, `time`, and `session3`. I want to use for loop or any other way is better but don't know how to choose column 1,2,3 at one time but column 1,2, 4 and etc. Any one has idea about that. The data is saved in pandas dataframe. I just don't know how to type it in Stackoverflow here. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to create a new dictionary for that.

Just directly slice your data frame whenever needed.

```
df[['name', 'time', 'session 1']]
```

If you think the following design can help you, you can set the `name` and `time` to be indexes (`df.set_index(['name', 'time'])`) and just simply

```
df['session 1']
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this helps a lot! I prefore the way of setting index!

Answer (score 1):

Organize it into a dictionary of dataframes:

```
dict_of_dfs = {f'df {i}':df[['name','time', i]] for i in df.columns[2:]}
```

Then you can access each dataframe as you would any other dictionary values:

```
>>> dict_of_dfs['df session1']
   name  time  session1
0  Alex   135        10
1   Lee   136         2
>>> dict_of_dfs['df session2']
   name  time  session2
0  Alex   135         3
1   Lee   136         6
```

Comment: I have a question about what is f'df {i}' means? I tried this but get an error about invalid syntax?

Comment: That's an `f-string`, which is available from python 3.6 onward. You could use `'df {}'.format(i)` instead